# Microphone not working in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, sound, pulseaudio, microphone

Microphone jacks are not working in Ubuntu 20.04. I've tried the case front jack and the mobo jack, and none worked. This is a 3-month old computer.
**Mobo jack work when I use Windows.** So I know the hardware is NOT the issue.

Details:

I've tried many things: pavucontrols, reloading/restarting alsa and pulseaudio, installing graphics card driver but nothing seems to work.

A few additional info:

**Input device from pavucontrols:**

[image]

**Ubuntu**

```
$ lsb_release -a | grep Description
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS
```

**Kernel**

```
$ uname -a
Linux dodo 5.13.0-44-generic #49~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed May 18 18:44:28 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

**Mobo**

```
$ sudo dmidecode -t 2 | grep "Manufacturer\|Product"
Manufacturer: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd.
Product Name: Z690 AORUS PRO
```

Audio

```
$ lspci -v | grep Audio
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Device 7ad0 (rev 11)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1aef (rev a1)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Side note: I bought a camera (Logitech 920s) to see if its mic would work. It didn't. Any ideas?